# 1980s movie about a stilt-like Angel/Griffin creature

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

When I was a kid I saw this preview to an interesting looking movie, it might have been a horror movie, but I didn't get those vibes.

I just remember it had long arms and legs, like those stilt creatures you can see on Google images. I think it had the face kind of like Vincent from the 1980s TV show *[Beauty and the Beast](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092319/)*. The creature was almost Griffin like, it had pink wings and I believe war a white gown.

I figured this might be a horror movie because when I was younger my parents would take me to this haunted house and there was an employee there who dressed like this creature and walked around.

People tried to say it's *[The Dark Crystal](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083791/)* (1982), but this was live-action and had a woman in her apartment with the creature and said something like "you're an angel" I have cut and pasted from various pictures and put together what I can sort of remember in my mind.

I figured this movie must have come around somewhere between 1983 to 1990. I have been searching for nearly 40 years and despite all the descriptions I put into the images, things come close, but nothing so far turns up this movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall where you saw this preview?  Was it a trailer for another movie or on TV?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you know of any specific images of creatures that resemble the one you're thinking of, it might be worth editing one or more of those into this question.

Comment: Stilt creature like https://www.instructables.com/Creepy-Creature-quad-Stilt-what-nightmares-are-ma-1/ ?

Comment: And, FWIW, the land striders were performed by people in costumes, as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8cZI1ZWA0o (which I think is a fan costume).

Comment: Behind the scenes images at https://www.pinterest.com/pin/470133648595840790/

Comment: Perhaps the creatures called Wheelers, from 1985's "Return to Oz"? Those creatures had wheels on stilted limbs, and wore masks.

Comment: Can you draw it for us? I'm struggling to imagine it from your description...

Comment: Could almost be Gozer the Gozerian from Ghost Busters?

Comment: Poltergeist?  https://youtu.be/FYe0Ija4xwc?si=MqpbdrqbAKkRgwnq

Comment: @Thomas Matthew Swindell - You mentioned a scene where a woman and the creature were in her apartment and one of them said "you're an angel." Which of them said that?

Comment: I hope I'm doing this right. The woman called the creature an angel, and I was at home seeing this preview on the tv. I know it wasn't poltergeist, I saw that a lot on HBO lol

Comment: I wish I could have had a picture, but I don't know how to add a picture to this